# Authors & profiles (and exclude ID's)

Tags: author, list

I'm facing the following:

I need to create a page with all authors and exclude multiple (id's). Strangely I'm using 'subscribers' to list the authors but it's working.

```
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>


        <?php
        // Get all users order by amount of posts
        $allUsers = get_users('orderby=post_count&order=DESC');
        $users = array();
        // Remove subscribers from the list as they won't write any articles
        foreach($allUsers as $currentUser)
        {
            if(!in_array( 'subscriber', $currentUser->roles ))
            {
                $users[] = $currentUser;
            }
        }
        ?>

<section class="content" role="main">
    <?php
        printf('
<h1>%s</h1>
', the_title());
        foreach($users as $user)
        {
            ?>


              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <?php echo get_avatar( $user->user_email, '200' ); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="caption">

                    <h4><?php echo $user->display_name; ?><small><?php echo stripslashes(esc_attr( get_the_author_meta('job_titel', $curauth->ID ) ) ); ?></small></h4>
                    <p> locatie </p>

                <p><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ); ?>"> Bekijk profiel</a></p>
                </div>



              </div>
              </div>


            <?php
        }
    ?>
```

How can I exclude id's from this list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let me say that it is not "Strangely" working using 'subscribers' role. Note that you are taking out the 'subscriber' role from the results.

The correct way to get only authors and exclude some IDs is using the `role` and `exclude` arguments of [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function:

```
    <?php

    $args = array(
         'role'    => 'author',
         //authors with ID 2 and 3 will be excluded
         'exclude'  => array( 2, 3 ),
         'orderby' => 'post_count',
         'order'   => 'DESC'
    );
    $authors = get_users( $args );

    ?>

    <section class="content" role="main">
    <?php
    printf( '<h1>%s</h1>', the_title() );

    foreach($authors as $author) {
    ?>

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <?php echo get_avatar( $author->user_email, '200' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="caption">

                <h4><?php echo $author->display_name; ?><small><?php echo stripslashes(esc_attr( get_the_author_meta('job_titel', $curauth->ID ) ) ); ?></small></h4>
                <p> locatie </p>

            <p><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $author->ID ); ?>"> Bekijk profiel</a></p>
            </div>



          </div>
          </div>


 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about the "exclude" argument?

```
get_users(array('orderby' => 'post_count',
                'order'=>'DESC',
                'exclude' => array(1,2,3,4,5,6));
```

Happy Coding,
Kuchenundkakao